# How to get Guid of all the applications installed on my blackberry phone.

Tags: blackberry, listener, guid

I am a blackberry application developer just a more than beginner. I want to build an application which can just determine that which (3rd party or native) application was opened and on what time?
I researched a quite bit but didn't found anything useful. My app would have an interface which will ask user for which applications to track. So is it possible to programmatically get the guid of that app and by using Global Event Listener in my app , i can compare the stored guid and guid obtained through global event listener.

***In short how to get Guid of all the applications installed on my phone.***

Please help me, if you have ever used or researched on such thing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800620/What_Is_-_System_Global_Events.html?nodeid=1163085&vernum=0

I don't think there is any way to get the GUIDs of all the applicatoins on the device, no matter whether they are running in background/foregraound or killed completely. GUIDs are availale only through certain APIs and you may find the list of all possible GUIDs that you can programatically get from the below URL:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/constant-values.html#net.rim.device.api.system.EventLogger.SYSTEM_LOG_GUID

Hope this helps..!